# How should my business objects be set up with a Spring/Hibernate project

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I'm setting up a Spring 3/Hibernate 3.6 application architecture for the first time and have all of the parts configured but need more information about the proper architecture design for a business layer.  Please provide advice or links to resources that will suggest the appropriate setup for a separate business layer between my controllers and DAOs.  Are there any suggested technologies for business objects or are POJOs normally used? Is the application simply divided with a separate folder, on the same level as my controllers, for business objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the size of your application, what your business objects do and how they depend on each other.

Typically the business objects will reside in one or more folders/packages depending on

- functionality, and
- their inter-dependence on each other

POJOs will normally do the job specially when you have Spring to take care of the transactionality and other cross cutting concerns.

I have also seen designs of very large applications where the services layer and DAOs are separated out into different applications for more loose coupling. So it really depends on various factors how you lay out the application structure.

Answer (score 1):

Use the business layer to annotate & define your transaction contexts (Transaction Control). 
You can package it as per you functional requirements. No set rule.
You can use simple java objects as long as you clearly separate your concerns.

Ensure that you do not use hibernate/db specific APIs in your business/service objects.

Use annotations on your POJOs to define relationships/mappings.