# Where to put complex algorithms in Spring REST app

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am building out a Spring REST app that takes an inputted address, tries to parse it and match it against verified addresses in a database. the structure is:

```
app
 -controller
 -model
 -service
 -dao
```

The piece that 'parses' out the address is a package--let's call it AddressParser. It has some complex regular expressions, algorithms, etc..

My question is where should I put this package exactly as per best practice? I could place it as a separate package under 'app' or within the model?

Comment: Check the following answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406386/how-should-my-business-objects-be-set-up-with-a-spring-hibernate-project

Comment: Rather structure it as follows: `app -> feature -> controller/model/service`. For your algorithms then have a separate package `logic` or anything you wish. Package by feature would be the best practice term. Packaging by layer causes very high coupling.